# I want my data on table to refreshed like a clock ticking, any suggestions?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

[here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E97i1.png). I'm calculating time difference between the given date and date now using pipe. What my problem is, I want it refreshing just like clock ticking. Any suggestions or another solution?

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'waitingTime'
})
export class WaitingTimePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any): any {
    var diff = new Date().getTime() - new Date(value).getTime()
    var msec = diff;
    var hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
    msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
    var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
    msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
    var ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
    msec -= ss * 1000;
    return hh + "hrs, " + mm + "mins, " + ss +"secs, ";
  }

}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:15px;">#</th>
            <th>Nickname</th>
            <th>Waiting Time</th>
            <th>action</th>
        </tr>
    
 
        <tr *ngFor="let d of data; let i = index">
            <td>{{index+ 1}}</td>
            <td>{{d.Nickname}}</td>
            <td >{{d.StartDateTime | waitingTime}}</td>
            <td>
                <button   icon="pi pi-check" 
                            styleClass="ui-button-success"></button>
                <button   icon="pi pi-replay" 
                            styleClass="ui-button-warning"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your component.ts

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs'; 

const secondsCounter = interval(1000);
secondsCounter.subscribe(n => {
  this.refresh()
});

refresh(){
  for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++){
   data[i].StartDateTime2 = transform(data[i].StartDateTime);
 }
}

transform(value: any): any {
var diff = new Date().getTime() - new Date(value).getTime()
var msec = diff;
var hh = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60 / 60);
msec -= hh * 1000 * 60 * 60;
var mm = Math.floor(msec / 1000 / 60);
msec -= mm * 1000 * 60;
var ss = Math.floor(msec / 1000);
msec -= ss * 1000;
return hh + "hrs, " + mm + "mins, " + ss +"secs, ";
}
```

Note that `StartDateTime2` is the string not Date as `StartDateTime` so you `component.html` template should be `<td >{{d.StartDateTime2}}</td>`

Comment: This will affect performance for the rows whose time expiration is low compared to others. The computation will still continue, even if the value is exhausted. You may introduce if condition, but that doesn't look clean code to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not executed at a certain (fixed) interval because the pipe is invoked only if some zone-change has been detected. I would use an `rxjs timer` and update an accessory member inside any `d` object of your list

Answer (score 0):

The better option is to create a separate component that uses rxjs operators to compute display value and also emits custom events. These events will help you to keep track of - Timer has expired, started and so on (Useful, if your actions column need to be updated). The component should accept seed time as input. So overall it should have the following

1. `@Input seedTime:number` (Should accept seed value from which the
   counter should start)
2. `@Output waitingEvent:EventEmitter<>` (Should emit event at logical
   point so that parent component can take certain actions)

Plus with this approach, you can also control, if timer for individual row needs to be stopped/paused explicitly.

**custom-comp.html**

```
{{formattedTime}}
```

**custom.comp.ts**

```
//... Excluded component definition for brevity

formattedTime = '';

@Input
seedTime:number;

@Output
waitingEvent = new :EventEmitter<'STARTED'|'STOPED'>();

interval$ = interval(1000);

const timer$ = this.interval$.pipe(
takeWhile(v < this.seedTime)
);


ngOnInit() {
this.timer$.subscribe(v=>{
this.formattedTime = this.callYourFormatFunction(this.seedTime - v);
});
}
```

Note that you can still enhance this design and pass observable to your pipe class, so that you don't have to explicity invoke `callYourFormatFunction`.